# How can I change multiple fields in multiple docs in one in MongoDB C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to add a social feature to my app.
Each user can send an invitation to other users and once the other user approves the invitation they are "friends".
The operation of approving an invitation includes several actions:

1. add each userId inside the other user friends list
2. remove the invitation from the user who sent the invitation
3. remove the approval invitation from the user receiving the invitation

I want to do all these actions as one atomic operation.

Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```
public class FriendsData
{
    public long _id;//UserId
    public long[] FriendsId;
    public long[] SentInvitations;
    public long[] AwaitingForApprovalInvitations;
}

public void ApproveInvitation(FriendsData userData, FriendsData friendData)
{
       m_friends.FindOneAndUpdate(string.Format("{{_id: {0}}} ", userData._id), Builders<FriendsData>.Update.AddToSet("FriendsId", friendData._id)
                                                                                                  .Pull("ActiveSentInvitations", friendData._id));

       m_friends.FindOneAndUpdate(string.Format("{{_id: {0}}} ", friendData._id), Builders<FriendsData>.Update.AddToSet("FriendsId", userData._id)
                                                                                       .Pull("AwaitingForApprovalInvitations", userData._id));
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'm worried that the DB will change between the two update actions.

Comment: Take a look a multi-document transactions: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transactions

Comment: transactions are not suitable for a standalone DB

Comment: You can possibly do the two updates in one update operation (in such case the update will be atomic) using Updates With Aggregation Pipeline.

Comment: `transactions are not suitable for a standalone DB` says who? you just make your server a single-node replicaset. that's all.

Comment: also `FindOneAndUpdate` is redundant here since you are not using the returned document. simply use `UpdateOne`. no point in wasting bandwidth.

Comment: @prasad_ do you mean BulkWrite?

Comment: @ĐĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ when I tried to use transactions I got that error.

Comment: @ĐĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ about the FindOneAndUpdate you are right.